# Getting data from a table meeting some requirements

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, logic

I'm stuck in a SQL logic problem.
I have a table "games" with some data where player1_id and player2_id are user ids that played with each other on a checkers match:

Each game starts with a different ambient, already specified in another table (keyed by "game_id" column). 
Assuming that everybody is online, an user can't replay the same game. 
**How can I select only users that wasn't played the games I didn't played yet to match with me?** 
An AJAX call will match two users that didn't played an specific game yet and put them to play.
No matter if the user was player1 or player2 , he can't repeat a game.
Thank you very much.

Tables:

**game_match**

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | game_id | player1_id | player2_id |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |         16 |         17 |
|  2 |       1 |         18 |         23 |
|  3 |       1 |         19 |         21 |
|  4 |       1 |         20 |         22 |
|  5 |       2 |         20 |         17 |
|  6 |       2 |         16 |         18 |
|  7 |       2 |         19 |         23 |
|  8 |       1 |         25 |         15 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
```

**Users**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 17 | Donald    |
| 18 | Margarida |
| 19 | Daisy     |
| 20 | Mickey    |
| 21 | Steve     |
| 22 | Raul      |
| 23 | Janis     |
| 24 | Michael   |
| 25 | Sergio    |
| 26 | Bill      |
| 27 | Alina     |
| 28 | Alana     |
| 29 | Harumi    |
| 30 | Danielle  |
| 31 | Lisa      |
+----+-----------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a table called `games` with a `game_id` that is *not* a unique primary key?

Comment: Edited. Sorry, the table name was wrong. Table "games" is the table with the game scenario.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you mean?  Your quest is hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table named `games` and a `$userid`, you can do this readily with `not exists`:

```
select g.*
from games g
where not exists (select 1 
                  from game_match gm 
                  where gm.game_id = g.game_id and gm.player1_id = $userid
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1 
                  from game_match gm 
                  where gm.game_id = g.game_id and gm.player2_id = $userid
                 ) ;
```

Note that you can implement the same logic with `or` and one subquery.  However, with the right indexes, two subqueries are more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With this query I'm getting the games I already played yet.

Comment: @Alrogatto . . . I think I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confuse when I'm under pressure. LOL. But thank you! I got it now and you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To get your users I would use a union in a subquery:

```
select * 
from users 
where id not in 
   (select player1_id as played
    from game_match 
    where player2_id = @logged_in_user
    union
    select player2_id 
    from game_match 
    where player1_id = @logged_in_user
    ) as played
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But with this query I'm getting the games I already played yet.

Comment: This query should return all users that you haven't played yet. It gets all the users you have played, then selects from the users table everything that isn't them. What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution using NOT EXISTS and INNER JOIN:

```
select name
from Users AS u
where not exists(
    select 1 
    from game_match AS gm INNER JOIN
    (select distinct game_id 
     from game_match
     where @current_user_id = player1_id OR @current_user_id = player2_id) gids
        USING(game_id)
    where u.id = gm.player1_id OR u.id = gm.player2_id
    );
```